# webtrends Rest API - Example?

Tags: api, webtrends

I have to build a custom dashboard that presents some data from a Webtrends account.

Can i get this information via api ? :

1) View and visitors for all pages and View/visitors for a single page (in a period range)

2) Stored Pages ( a list of all urls saved for my site in webtrends .. so i can choose for which one get more information in point 1) )

3) Overall like point 1) but from the start of the web site until now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, maybe you have a look at the API documentation. The URL is http://product.webtrends.com/dxapi/

1. yes. You can filter your request for a special page or you can get all pages. You just need to request the standard report "pages"
2. The pages report has a list of your pages, just limited by the WebTrends Table Limit (10000 unique analysed pages, 2000 shown pages).
3. You can define a start date + end date or you request a whole year. It is not possible to request 2007-01-01 to 2011-01-01 due to the fact, that webtrends never stores more than one year in a fasttrends database. If you would request this custom data rate within the WebTrends UI, it would also not work. I think you would have to request each year and summarize it within your dashboard. Remember, webtrends stores daily metrics just for the last 180 days by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A last thing... this pages have a param defined in url to set the language (lang_EN... lang_FR). I need to set report to group by this param. Thanks to the linked documentation i found the param "search" and using it i can grab only some URL, as i want, an then i process sums over this data to find total view and so on. Is this a good method ? Thank you again!

Comment: The first row from the API is the total number, so you don't have to summarize by your own. Maybe you could also create a custom report and add your language parameter as a metric and you count it. A guide and how it could look like: http://www.webtrendsoutsider.com/2008/how-to-display-any-kpi-page-as-a-measure-column/

Comment: Could you kindly give me an example of URL for this call ? i cant get sum for every data, but only for "Views" (i'm using the url generator at the moment). If i need to get Views and avarage Time for every pages with string lang_EN which structure of URL i have to call ?? Could you confirm that i can't grab sum for trends ? and i cant use the search parameter for trend period ?

Comment: Depending on your measures, maybe views is the only one who could be sum. E.g. if you see your pages, to summarzie the visits would totally be wrong, because within one visit you have one or more page views. A standard report with summarized visits would be "single-page visits". In which report is your average time? Is it a custom report? How did you configure the measures? Yes, if you select "Trend" there is no summary in the first row!

Comment: I can't create custom report. I must get only data from Standard reports. Now i use report: "CS - Pages". (In a while i'm going to add other question about Webtrends API limit)